# Do high voltage modules produce electromagnetic waves?

Tags: high-voltage, electromagnetic

I have been experimenting with one of these 3-6V high voltage modules:

[image: High Voltage Module]

I know the specifics of how they work, although I have recently been wondering about something. In a [video by ElectroBOOM](https://youtu.be/HWVfGTSiooU?t=678), he created extremely high voltage sparks and he was worried about producing X-rays. Although nowhere near the power that he had, could these high voltage modules also be producing some kind of electromagnetic wave?

Let me be more specific, can it produce any electromagnetic waves above the frequency of visible light, with any damage/risk to human health?

Comment: They can produce electromagnetic waves, as any alternating current can. But not X-rays for sure

Comment: @DKNguyen I updated my answer to be more specific.

Comment: Well UV is hazardous to human health and sparks do produce that.

Comment: @DKNguyen What size of a spark would one need to actually cause any noticeable harm?

Comment: Well the damage is first to the eyes. And sparks are so short that any spark intense enough to damage your eyes would probably also cause so much visible light that it would be damaging too. So UV is probably not your first concern there. The ozone from the sparks would probably make you sick first.

Comment: @DKNguyen Well, yeah, I presume the electric welding tools are producing it, so the welders do have eyes protection.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah yeah. I guess welding is one of the most common examples of prolonged sparks, as well as being particularly intense.

Comment: Arc welding produces enough UV that it will even burn you skin like a sun burn when you are as close as the person welding.  A campfire produces enough UV to burn your skin although much milder.

Comment: @PerryWebb I accidentally gave myself a welding suntan a couple of months ago while doing a lot of welding while wearing shorts & t-shirt :P

Comment: @PerryWebb I think a campfire "sunburn" is mostly due to the very high intensity infra-red. Could be wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xrays are produced in very small gaps to match the 1/4 wavelength or harmonics with a radiator horn antenna and repeated for digital imaging purposes are safe in dental offices.

One spark is not going to harm you (unless it is an EMP) as it is the cumulative energy in a narrow band-limited by the wavelength of the arc path length and a few subharmonics.

Eyes are most susceptible to IR heat which can be produced from many forms of energy including microwave and damage potential becomes more susceptible with increased frequencies above the microwave to Xray and Gamma rays.

Arc welding is a perfect example of risk, thus IR filters are used to block that in welding masks.

But a single spark is very low risk and the energy increases with the current and power levels.   The MicroBoom sparkplug example or similar is very low risk compared to welding currents unless accumulated energy matches that of welding currents (100A x time).

More specify metrics of wavelength * power * time are beyond the scope of this question.

Another example is old VRT TV's which produced low levels of UV when the currents hit the phosphor gaps on the glass. So all those TV's used leaded-glass which attenuated the X-RAYs to safe levels.

High doses of accumulated XRAYs cause;

```
Aging Skin
Skin Cancer
Wrinkles
Inflamed Cornea
```

The colour of the arc energy increases in temperature above cool-white 6000'K in fires can also be used by foresters to detect sources of fire. The arcs of molecular gas combustion that are hotter creates the shorter wavelengths of energy.  e.g.
https://www.industrialcontrolsonline.com/honeywell-c7927

Hydrogen being the lightest element reacts with any oxygen and other carbon compounds and depending on the atomic size raises the activation and combustion energy at the same time.  e.g. Hydrogen bombs are used to detonate "atomic" bombs which use fission to split atoms with extreme short wavelengths to emit an EMP **e**lectro**m**agnetic **p**ulse with lots of stored energy to follow from the E=mc² of the material.

I recall reading from MIL_STD Handbooks the experiments documented by the US Military to measure the susceptible to damage curves for radiation from DC to Gamma Rays back when I was an EE in R&D for aerospace in the late '70's.  the curves are well-defined for exposure and wavelength.  This means you don't want your head beside an active 100W Radar antenna or mobile phone antenna like they did during WWII. Tank operators used to faint when the RADAR was on and they had their head up beside it. So the response was, they fainted.  Present day mobile phones are design below safe mW/gm power levels. 5G is more susceptible so power levels must be reduced again and more elevated mobile antenna farms are needed to offer the same safety levels with the reduced range from [Friis](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Friis_transmission_equation) Losses.

HV/ULF is designed to be safe.

I also recall the scam in the '80's where researchers got gov't funds to promote that 60 Hz power lines and breaker panels caused cancer.  They were later found to be frauds. Power Lines can emit harmful energy , but not if they are elevated high enough with Friis Losses in air with inverse distance square law attenuation in E fields.  120/240Vac E-fields have no loss due to absorption and go right thru you safely.